# Hello I'm trying to port an ASP.NET sample from C#(?) to VB and come unstuck as I dont understand the C# Language

Tags: c#, asp.net, porting

Hello and thank you for reading my thread.

I'm new aps.net 4.5+ and am trying to port a C# asp.net sample to visual basic.

I've attempted to follow the instructions as best I can with my limited skills.

[The ORIGINAL article is here...](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-45/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/create_the_data_access_layer)

The article is in several steps and i'm on step 2.

```
ORIGINAL CODE - PRODUCT CONTEXT CLASS
=====================================
using System.Data.Entity; 
namespace WingtipToys.Models 
{ 
public class ProductContext : DbContext 
{ 
    public ProductContext() : base("WingtipToys")  
    { 
    } 
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; } 
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; } 
} 
}
```

The bits that are confusing me are the code statements with the angle brackets in the code above.
Also the following statements

1 "public class productcontext : dbcontext"

2 "public dbset categories {get; set;}"

3 "public dbset products {get; set;}"

where does DBSET come into it? and what does it mean when the items are encased in the angle brackets?

I dont wish to seed the database with the data like its done in the sample.
I already have a database and am confortable withgetting the data from the db

I tried to search for the same project (wingtip toys + visual basic) but it failed to find a vb sample)

basically having never worked with entitiy's before its a little confusing.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Since there are so many c# examples and reference materials on the interwebs, it would be worth your time to spend an hour learning the basic syntax.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
Imports System.Data.Entity

Namespace WingtipToys.Models

Public Class ProductContext
    Inherits DbContext

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New("WingtipToys")
    End Sub

    Public Property Categories As DbSet(Of Category)
    Public Property Products As DbSet(Of Product)
End Class

End Namespace
```

I'm glad that someone else ported it already, and am more glad that you are using VB.NET.

As a professional programmer since 1992 who has forgotten more programming languages than most people will ever learn, VB.NET is my language of choice because it retains the readability of earlier forms of BASIC, with none of the past limitations of BASIC.

As a new developer, the clearer, close to pseudo-code syntax of VB.NET makes it easier to focus more on the actual work being done, and less on translating arcane symbols that date back to the 1970's when every byte was precious, and languages used single character symbols to save space.

I think that biggest possible problem with VB.NET is that it can be so easy that it lets programmers get away with writing sloppier code than other languages, but IMO most of the code I have ever seen in any language is not that well written, and bad code in VB.NET may be bad but readable, while bad code in a language with C-style syntax can easily be totally incomprehensible.

So I would encourage you to learn good programming practices, especially using intuitive variable and method names, and keep your methods short and solving a single problem, and name them by asking yourself how easy will it be to understand what you were thinking 2 years from now.

Comment: Thanks Ken, its wise advice and I will do my best to try to do as you advise. And I completely agree with you on the readability thing.

Answer (score 2):

use [Telerik code Convertor](http://converter.telerik.com/) . it is a free and simple VB to C# and C# to VB code converter.

Comment: Thank you I found someone has already ported it and uploaded it to asp.net :D its at http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vstudio/ASPNET-45-Web-Forms-f37f0f63

Comment: With Ref to BillTheLizard's comments... The link to the sample i found is already in the above thread...  In case you cannot see it.... It is at...  http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vstudio/ASPNET-45-Web-Forms-f37f0f63

Answer (score 1):

Invest some time to learn the basics of C#, you will not regret it.

Why do you port it to Visual Basic? Because you do not understand C#? May be you should spend little more time with it, you might end up liking C# than VB, (at least that's the case for me :) )

`

> "public class productcontext : dbcontext"

`Here it defins a class named`productcontext`which inherits from`DbContext`.

> 2 "public dbset categories {get; set;}"
>
> 3 "public dbset products {get; set;}"

Both above lines defines two properties "categories" and "product" using [Auto property syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) of C#.

Further, I believe this class is generated from [EntityFramework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx), **you should not try to convert it yourself**, but regenerate into VB.

I'm not exactly how to do that, but I guess if you get the `edmx` (which holds the entity model in XML format), and add it to a VB project it will regenerate the code in VB. (Never tried this though).

Still, you must learn the basics to be better at this.